# Alternate Octave Commands for Matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing, octave, video

can you tell me how to write video data to file..
what is the alternate of these 4 commands in octave

```
videoreader('bg.mp4');  
readframe(v);  
videowriter('bg1.avi');  
writevideo(newv,k);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Octave user, but the [Video](https://octave.sourceforge.io/video/overview.html) package appears to do these things.

Good luck!